# I can't send POST request with AJAX due to CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, cors

Im trying to use an API for my website. I am trying to send a POST request with JSON data. But when I try to send the request I get an error code. I have tried sending the request with curl and that works without any problem.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish/api/v1/prefilled' from origin 'http://192.168.0.90' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Curl command

```
curl --data '{"format":"svg","size":300,"message":{"value":"test","editable":true},"amount":{"value":100,"editable":false},"transparent":true}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --output output.png --request POST https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish/api/v1/prefilled
```

I have enabled Access-Control-Allow-Origin in apache configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName web
        ServerAlias web
        DocumentRoot /var/www/web
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS"
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish/api/v1/prefilled',
    data: '{"format":"svg","size":300,"message":{"value":"test","editable":true},"amount":{"value":100,"editable":false},"transparent":true}',
    headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Guessing that https://mpc.getswish.net/qrg-swish/api/v1/ needs to allow incoming request from http://192.168.0.90

Comment: `getswish.net` is your server? As that is where the Access-control-allow-origin header has to be used

Comment: But I can send the request from curl and not ajax. And the request is sent from the same server.

Comment: Because curl ignores/doesn't use cors headers, only browsers use those

Comment: No it is not my server. It is an API for generating QR-codes for payments.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that thank you!

Comment: Then you will need to fetch the data server side or use a cors proxy

Comment: From your own backend code(server) call the API ,not  directly from js .Then call the ajax from your own backend code(server(

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an API that enforces CORS, then it probably means they don't want you to call it from a web browser at all. What you need to do is make your own back-end which your front-end will talk to. So your AJAX call needs to go to your own back-end, which calls the API, and sends the result back. The back-end can call the API without CORS limits. Only web browsers enforce CORS for security measures.